# Preview video from thumbnail

Tags: php, video-streaming, video-processing

Recently stumbled upon a stock video footage site [http://www.pond5.com/stock-video-footage/1/*.html](http://www.pond5.com/stock-video-footage/1/%2a.html) , and saw that they had a preview of a video when the user hovered over a thumbnail. I want to recreate this, because it seems like useful practice and it will allow me to workout my web developing muscles.

I would like to be able to preview a video when a user hovers over a thumbnail.
For example like [pond5.com](http://www.pond5.com/stock-video-footage/1/%2a.html). Audio is not necessary, but I would like it to look smooth like a video rather than a video preview that contains a frame every 5 seconds.

On pond5.com, I originally thought they used a gif, but it plays very smoothly. Some also contain audio. As far as I thought, audio can't be used in .GIFs

Is this a case where I would have to just upload a 2nd video for the preview?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: yes, basically, you need two videos, a full version and a preview version, since creating a preview video on the fly would take time, and that is definitely not your goal.

Comment: You could have onhover install a miniature lightweight video player that streams and loads the actual video... but that would be a bit overly resource intensive.  Better to just do it as Dexter suggested.

Comment: Creating a 2nd video that is lower quality seemed like a very simple solution, almost too simple. I don't have too much experience with server side scripting, so deep down inside I was hoping there would be some neat PHP script to learn that converts videos on upon uploading. Thank you both for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pond5, the website you specifically mentioned, creates a video thumbnail with watermark and lowered quality and stores it. It is then played back using JavaScript to dynamically load a div element that contains the flash player. So no GIFs are involved. You do need to upload a 2nd video, but the steps to this project are as follows:

1. Server-side video thumbnail/watermarking: Not sure if there are any PHP packages that are up to the task on this one. I would write a more powerful program in C++ or C#. If you go with C#, quick and easy solution would be Microsoft Expression Encoder.
2. Flash/Silverlight/HTML5 video player: To play the video.
3. Client-side JavaScript: To load the fancy popup and the aforementioned video player. Note that you might need to use PHP and a database engine to load the thumbnail URL for the video requested.

This is what Pond5, and what many other stock-footage sites use, and the basic outline of what you would need to do to achieve similar results.

Comment: This definitely helped paint a better picture of what I will need. For this particular project, I will stay more with just using PHP and Javascript this time around. Thank you for the thorough answer John.